# Does $e^{ae^{bt}}$ appear in any real applications

Tags: functions

I wonder if someone knows a real life application of the function $e^{ae^{bt}}?$

I found this solution for a differnatial equation and was surprised to see something like this. It would be interesting to see if there are other applications to this type of function.

I am especially intersted in applications in physics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function

Comment: Depends on the values of $a,b.$ See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-1_Gumbel_distribution

Comment: Are there any applications in physics?